# How to round off in swig template

Tags: html, node.js, swig-template

I am using swig template to send auto mailer in my organisation.
I have googled everything and couldn't find anything about how we can round off the value in swig.
My code is:

```
<td style="background:#ff4d4d;text-align: center;padding: 7px 24px;border-radius: 5px;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;">{{cnt.p/cnt.total*100 }}%</td>
```

and in this I want to round off "{{cnt.p/cnt.total*100 }}" to upto 2 decimal places.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use any JavaScript statement in `{{}}` in Swig. In this case, the code would be:

```
<td>{{Math.round(cnt.p/cnt.total*10000)/100}}%</td>
```

However, please note [Swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig) is not maintained any more. Suggest using Mozilla's [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/), which has syntax very similar to Swig.